# "Failed to connect to the SC2 websocket. Is it up?"

Tags: python, connection, starcraftgym

I am trying to run the Deepmind Environment for Starcraft II, following this [tutorial](https://github.com/deepmind/pysc2)

After running:

```
$ python -m pysc2.bin.play --map Simple64
```

I get this error:

```
raise ConnectError("Failed to connect to the SC2 websocket. Is it up?")
```

within the `pysc2.lib.remote_controller`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be obvious for some, but it took me 25 minutes, so I'll put it here.

> The SC2 websocket is up once you completely installed and started the game.
>
> Not only the battlenet interface.

*Note*: Make sure that the game is in the current version (update if possible)

Comment: Hi, I have a naive question: what do you mean by starting the game?  Does it mean you open the game and then run the python?

Comment: Exactly, you need to run the game, as if you would play it.

Comment: Thank you for the kindly reply! But it didn't work.... Do I need to play the specific game or just stay at the entry of the game?

Comment: Oh, I made it after I finished the 25.6GB update of this game...